# Time signal shifted in amplitude, FIR filter with scipy.signal

Tags: python, scipy, filtering

I am implementing a bandpass filter in Python using `scipy.signal` (using the firwin function). My original signal consists of two frequencies (w_1=600Hz, w_2=800Hz). There might be a lot more frequencies that's why I need a bandpass filter.

In this case I want to filter the frequency band around 600 Hz, so I took 600 +/- 20Hz as cutoff frequencies. When I implemented the filter and reproduced the signal in the time domain using lfilter the frequency is fine.

The amplitude is reproduced in the right magnitude as well. But the problem is the signal is shifted in the y-direction. For example: `s(t)=s_1(t)+s_2(t)` with `s_1(t)=sin(w_1 t)+3` and  `s_2(t)=sin(w_2 t)` returns a filtered signal which varies around 0 but not [2,4]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I adapted one filter to get the zerofrequency and another bandpassfilter to get the 600 Hz frequency. Passzero has to be true just for the zerofrequency then it works.
I'm not yet happy with the phase delay but I'm working on it.

## 1)bandpass 600 Hz:

`taps_bp = bandpass_fir(ntaps, lowcut, highcut, fs)`

#### Function for the bandpassfilter

`def bp_fir(ntaps, lowcut, highcut, fs, window = 'hamming')
    taps = scipy.signal.firwin(ntaps,[lowcut, highcut],nyq, pass_zero=False)
    return taps`

## 2)zerofrequency filter

`taps_zerofrequency = zero_fir(ntaps, zerofreq=1, fs)`

#### Function for the zerofrequency filter

`def zero_fir(ntaps, zerofreq, fs, window = 'hamming')
    taps = scipy.signal.firwin(ntaps,[zerofreq],nyq, pass_zero=True)
    return taps`

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at the documentation: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.firwin.html

Check the argument pass_zero.

To be speciffic, that missing 3.0 is the 0 frequency, non-periodic, or "DC" offset.  You should not be getting this 3.0 from the output signal.  If you are resolute, however, try:

```
scipy.signal.firwin(numtaps, [1,600-20,600+20,800-20,800+20,nyquist], pass_zero=True)
```

Not sure if that will work though.

Comment: Ok, so this helped me a lot to understand the firwin function better. Your code gives me the zero frequency of the complete signal. As a result I get the reference signal (with a quite high gain because due to pass_zero=True the gain is scaled so that gain(f=0)=1). Additionally the filtered signal includes the zero frequency (my +3). Is that right?